# Serialize instance of a class deriving from DynamicObject class

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, expandoobject, dynamicobject

I have a class that derives from DynamicObject class. On calling JsonConvert.SertializeObject, none of the dynamic properties are serialized.

Class is defined as,

```
        public class Component : DynamicObject
        {
        // The inner dictionary.
        public Dictionary<string, object> dictionary
            = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        // If you try to get a value of a property 
        // not defined in the class, this method is called.
        public override bool TryGetMember (
            GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
            {
            // Converting the property name to lowercase
            // so that property names become case-insensitive.
            string name = binder.Name.ToLower();

            // If the property name is found in a dictionary,
            // set the result parameter to the property value and return true.
            // Otherwise, return false.
            return dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out result);
            }

        // If you try to set a value of a property that is
        // not defined in the class, this method is called.
        public override bool TrySetMember (
            SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
            {
            // Converting the property name to lowercase
            // so that property names become case-insensitive.
            dictionary[binder.Name.ToLower()] = value;

            // You can always add a value to a dictionary,
            // so this method always returns true.
            return true;
            }
        }
```

then i do this,

```
dynamic component = new Component();
component.test = "123";

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(component);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override [`DynamicObject.GetDynamicMemberNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.getdynamicmembernames.aspx):

```
public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
{
    return dictionary.Keys;
}
```